# javascript redirect page

Tags: javascript

Есть страничка с картинкой размером x на у пикселей. Если пользователь попал мышкой в область на картинке с координатами допустим x1+-10 на y1+-10 пикселей - его редиректит на другую страницу. Т.е. по попаданию в некоторую область редирект на другую страничку

Как это можно сделать?

Спасибо!

Comment: Важна то что бы пользователь просто попал на картинку ? или он должен не находится на краю?

Comment: вот как сделать редирект по наведению на ссылку а как сделать редирект по наведению на определенную область в картинке? <a onMouseOver="document.location.href='you_page.htm'" >Your_text_here</a>

Comment: чтобы пользователь попал на область в картинке. картинка допустим 100х100 пикселей, если пользователь попадает в область картинки, в центр картинки в квадрат 5х5 пикселей, происходит редирект на другую страничку

Answer (score 0):

Можно так. (в снипеттах stackoverflow не работает ***только в браузере***)

```js
document.onmousemove = function(event){
if (event.clientX > 10 && event.clientY > 10){
location.href="https://google.com"; // ссылка
}
}
```

```css
body {
border:10px solid #fa0;
height:calc(100vh - 40px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот примерно так.
Дал `20px` вместо 5 что бы здесь было легче увидеть работу скрипта.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.red_img').bind('mousemove',function(event){
    var img_left = $(this).offset().left+$(this).width()/2-50;
    var img_top = $(this).offset().top+$(this).height()/2-50;
    if(event.clientX > img_left && event.clientX < img_left +100 && event.clientY > img_top && event.clientY < img_top +100){
      console.log("ПОПАЛСЯ");
      //И редирект
      //window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
.red_img{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <img class="red_img" src ="http://301redirects.net/301-redirect.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: @vilfred Вот так хотели?

Comment: вообще ничего не происходит  <html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>тест</title>
<style>
.red_img{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>     
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<font color=white>A visualisation for sky elements zoom by mousewheel or touchpad scroll</font><p>
 <script src="1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <img class="red_img" src="http://301redirects.net/301-redirect.jpg"/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @vilfred еще раз посмотрите